# Как вытащить количество строк по определенной дате в PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Необходимо сделать SELECT из таблицы. Пример:

```sql
str|int|timestamp
qwe|123|2019-12-16 00:00:00
ert|456|2019-12-16 00:01:00
yui|789|2019-12-16 00:02:00
...
```

Запрос:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE timestamp LIKE '2019-12-16%'
```

PostgreSQL выдает ошибку:

```sql
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown
  Подсказка: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Позиция: 54
```

Погуглил, попытался сделать так:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE timestamp LIKE '2019-12-16%'::timestamp
```

Не помогло. Как исправить ошибку? Может есть другие способы?

Comment: Надо просто обрезать поле до даты. См. `date_trunc()`.

Comment: @Akina это как подзапрос использовать?

Comment: Это - посмотреть справку по функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите полноценное условие поиска по диапазону

```
timestamp >= '2019-12-16' and timestamp <  '2019-12-16' + interval '1 day'
```

---

Можете встречать варианты с `date_trunc` или с `timestamp::date = '2019-12-16'` какими-нибудь. Имейте в виду, что такие способы не могут использовать индекс по этому полю. Лучше не извращаться, а использовать простое и очевидное условие на вхождение значения в диапазон.

Comment: Запрос: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table where timestamp = '2019-12-16' and timestamp<  '2019-12-16' + interval '1 day'

SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type interval: "2019-12-16"
  Позиция: 88

Comment: @Brainofmadness, `... '2019-12-16'::timestamp + interval ...`